# well founded induction / difference to strong induction

Tags: induction, order-theory, natural-numbers

We are given a chocolate bar with $n$  pieces (squares) and we already know by strong induction that $n-1$ are needed to break it in individual parts. https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1134/lectures/04/Small04.pdf (p. 22)

But now I need to prove this with well-founded induction. My problem is I do not really understand what I should do differently compared to strong induction. I know that we have to do induction over $\mathbb{N}$ and that $\mathbb{N}$ has a well-founded order with $ <$, but how do I proceed from there? and what the is main difference to the usual induction?

Comment: Strong induction is simply well-founded induction over the well-founded order $\langle\Bbb N,\le\rangle$, so in this case there really is no difference.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, now it is clear

Comment: You’re welcome.